# Copy lines from one text file to multiple text files based on first column values C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new in C#. I have a Text file with (;) separated values saved in specific folder. I want to read the text file and copy the lines based on the first column values and put them in multiple text files. Furthermore I want the filename of the copied file automatically saved with the specific filename. - `iMAN_SS_KBH_ + (the copied column values) + date.txt` . How can I program this using C#.

> 4363594-3;;332C_MI_TE3F82;K3;MI-3E57911;3;1;;ZZPI;THES;WLEN;
>   
>   4363594-3;;341A;000;MI-5E41565;1;1;;ZZPI;THES;WLEN;
>   
>   4363594-3;;341A;12;MI-2D79976;1;1;;ZZPI;THES;WLEN;
>   
>   4340007-3;;90101-0133;000;3166916-4;1;1;;ZZPI;KOKO;LRR;
>   
>   4340007-3;;90101-0133;018;EN61V1216;4;1;;ZZPI;KOKO;LRR;
>   
>   4340007-3;;90101-0133;031;1296651-4;4;1;;ZZPI;KOKO;LRR;

In the example above I need to read and copy lines with the values 4363594-3 and 4340007-3 into two separate text files with the assigned filename I mentioned.

Thank you very much and I hope someone can help me with the programming.

Comment: "How can I program this using C#?" - I'd recommend using TDD as good practice. Probably a bit too broad advice, so comment. If you need more specific help - edit question to be more specific.

Comment: I don't know where to start but what I have in mind is to read the text file look for the value of the first columns and loop into it compare it and if the next value doesn't match the previous one then it will copy into another file and it will continue with the next value and copy the next into another text file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start:

```
//To read all lines from a text file:
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

foreach(var line in lines)
{
  //Separate by semi-colon:
  var splitText = line.Split(';');

  //Do what ever you want with all pieces like this:
  var piece = splittext[0];
}
```